# Community Detection Louvain algorithm's Modularity not changing when adding edge weights

Tags: networkx, modularity

When adding edge weights to my graph, the Louvain algorithm Modularity score doesnt change compared to having no edge weights(it stays at about 0.8). I computed the weights as a euclidean simmilarity score between attached nodes, so they range between 0 and 1.

Im pretty new to Community Detection, so what could be causing this issue?

### EDIT:

```py
import community
import networkx as nx 
from community import best_partition
from community import modularity

#Reduced dictionary explanation: the key(eg. BIDU) is one node, 
#the nested key(eg: 865326452400504832) is the second node, 
#and the value is the edge weight computed as the average 
#Euclidean similarity (based on a feature vector) of the
# nested key with all other nested keys within the same 
#key(eg.0.7885422115698439 = vector similarity between 865326452400504832 and 865326457001697280)

similarity_reduced = {"BIDU": {865326452400504832: 0.7885422115698439, 865326457001697280: 0.7885422115698439},
 'JD':{865326452400504832: 0.6138829308835345,865326457001697280: 0.6259871779548237, 869811004955389952: 0.4513278972685143},
 'TCEHY':{865326452400504832: 0.6020128491158321,865326457001697280: 0.6078782014152254, 869528165076447232: 0.42134883896121356}}

  
def create_graph():
  G = nx.Graph()
  for keys, values in similarity_reduced.items():
    G.add_node(keys)
    for key, value in values.items():
      G.add_edge(keys, key, weight = value)
      if key in G.nodes():
          continue
      else :
          G.add_node(key)
  return G

G = create_graph()
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attributes)
print(nx.info(G))

Returns:
Name: 
Type: Graph
Number of nodes: 7
Number of edges: 8
Average degree:   2.2857

#These are all the edges in the graph
list(G.edges(data=True))

Returns:
"[('BIDU', 865326452400504832, {'weights': 0.7885422115698439}),
 ('BIDU', 865326457001697280, {'weights': 0.7885422115698439}),
 (865326452400504832, 'JD', {'weights': 0.6138829308835345}),
 (865326452400504832, 'TCEHY', {'weights': 0.6020128491158321}),
 (865326457001697280, 'JD', {'weights': 0.6259871779548237}),
 (865326457001697280, 'TCEHY', {'weights': 0.6078782014152254}),
 ('JD', 869811004955389952, {'weights': 0.4513278972685143}),
 ('TCEHY', 869528165076447232, {'weights': 0.42134883896121356})]
"

partitions = best_partition(G, weight="weight")
mod = modularity(partitions, G, weight="weight")
mod
Returns:
"0.1484375"

´´´
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your code?  There are lots of things that could be causing it.  Without  seeing what you've done, my best guess is that you've tried to assign the weights but either you've made a mistake in assigning them or (more likely) you haven't told the networkx command where to get the weights for its calculations.

Comment: Still hard to see from your code. Could you create a small example with a small number of nodes and edges (e.g. 10 edges) and share the data. Then we could reproduce your example and debug it more easily. Since even in default [modularity](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.quality.modularity.html) uses "weight", have you really compared against `modularity(G, partitions, weight=None)`? (Additionally the order of parameters looks not like the latest networkx version).

Comment: Sparky05- Switching the parameter order in Modularity as you suggested is raising the issue "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_directed'"

Comment: Checking my code again, I see the issue was in using "weight" instead of "weights" in the modularity parameters. With my full dataset it improved the modularity by 0.001, which is still less than I expected.